# Powershell file quoting

Tags: powershell

I'd like help on understanding the quoting rules for files in Powershell v5.1. I'm working with paths that sometimes have spaces and sometimes trailing backslashes if they are directories.

I've got this:

```
PS> echo "C:\Temp\"
C:\Temp\
PS> echo "C:\Temp 1\"
C:\Temp 1\
PS> .\myecho "C:\Temp\"
C:\Temp\
PS> .\myecho "C:\Temp 1\"
C:\Temp 1"
PS> .\myecho 'C:\Temp 1\'
C:\Temp 1"
```

Where `echo` is the built in command aka Write-Output and `myecho` is a C program which just prints out the values of `argv[]`. In particular, the last two are unexpected.

It seems like PS applied different rules for built-ins and external programs, and depending if the path has a space or not.

Can anyone explain or point me to the rules?

[edit]
To address the comment of Jeroen Mostert:

```
PS> .\myecho --% "C:\Temp 1\"
C:\Temp 1"
PS> .\myecho --% 'c:\temp 1\'
'c:\temp
1\'
```

(in the second case, the C program received argv[1]=`'c:\temp` and argv[2]=`1\'`)

[edit 2] The further comments of Jeroen: Printing out what the C program receives from `GetCommandLine()`

```
PS> .\myecho "C:\Temp\"
"C:\temp\myecho.exe" C:\Temp\
PS> .\myecho "C:\Temp 1\"
"C:\temp\myecho.exe" "C:\Temp 1\"
PS> .\myecho 'C:\Temp 1\'
"C:\temp\myecho.exe" "C:\Temp 1\"
```

Comment: As an aside, you can use `.\myecho --%`. `--%` instructs PowerShell to stop parsing what comes after and pass the argument as-is, which is often helpful to prevent you from having to work around quoting arguments to external programs. Using string variables (not hard-coded paths) also often helps.

Comment: Thanks, see my edit.

Comment: Ah, but *now* you are down to the parsing rules of your C library. PowerShell does exactly what you ask of it -- it passes the literal string to the command, which then has the job of taking it apart into `argv`. This will have rules like "\ is an escape character, so \" is a literal quote" and other such beautiful things necessary to parse command lines on Windows.

Comment: What might work is passing `"$($path.Replace('\', '\\').Replace('"', '\"'))"`, where `$path` is a string variable containing your path without any escaping. This should produce paths parseable by most commands expecting the Windows rules. You can make this a little helper function. (I still can't tell you what logic PowerShell will use, exactly, if you don't use `--%` -- I try to avoid the issue of escaping paths to external commands altogether if possible, which works beautifully if you keep doing everything in PowerShell itself.)

Comment: I altered my program to also print the value of `GetCommandLineA()`, i.e. the command line before the C library gets hold of it. Now I can see that PS will convert single quotes to double, and remove the quotes if the quoted text has no spaces. After that, the C library (it's MSVC) strips the opening double quote but treats a trailing backslash-quote as an escaped quote (and doesn't mind if the quoted text now has no terminating quote). That explains what I see and (I suppose) exonerates PowerShell!

Comment: To be precise, it's probably not removing any quotes -- `'literal'` is simply one way of writing down a PowerShell string, `"literal"` is another (one has no substitution, the other does). After it has the actual value of the string (`literal`), it will add quotes as necessary to make commands work. Or, at least, it tries (I think this approach will work fine for most things following the rules of `cmd`, which will treat the trailing backslash case correctly). Command line escaping is never a fun thing, which is why PowerShell's object approach is much nicer.

Comment: I agree. See my second edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that iterating and outputting `argv[]` is not the same as outputting the actual (literal) command line, as you have noted. To do that, you can use the `GetCommandLine` API.

In any case, you may find the following article helpful:

[Windows IT Pro - Running Executables in PowerShell](http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/running-executables-powershell)

There's a `showargs.exe` in the associated download that uses the `GetCommandLine` API to output the actual/literal command line, without any interpretation or parsing.